# error is showing in viewpager adding view

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-viewpager

here is view pager code for xml layout view pager

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

this code showing error in view pager line that contain "((ViewPager) container.addView(viewlayout);" which is inside instantiateItem function to adding view in view pager. how to solve this error plz help out.

```
public class Fullscreenimage extends PagerAdapter {
public Integer[] images1 = { R.drawable.s_1, R.drawable.s_2, R.drawable.s_3 };

public Context mContext;

public Fullscreenimage(Context context) {
    super();
    this.mContext = context;

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
    View viewlayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_view,container,false);
    ImageView imageview=(ImageView) viewlayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
    imageview.setImageResource(images1[position]);
     ((ViewPager) container.addView(viewlayout);
    return viewlayout;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
In Your code 

((ViewPager) container.addView(viewlayout,0);
```

In the above line in your code you missed ")". that's the reason it's giving an error.
Try this then it will be fixed.

```
((ViewPager) container).addView(viewlayout,0);
```

Comment: error is in ((ViewPager)container.addView(viewlayout,0);..left-hand side of assignment must be variable....whether i have to assign ViewPager or not..??

Comment: Check the answer once again.